# T-SQL Attribute Days to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a piece of work where I feel it could be done better/more accurately.

I attributing some Entry DateTimes to specified Targets.

There are 3x Target Days (when activities should ideally be done - on the day, 3 days after, 5 days after) and multiple Entry DateTimes (when they actually took place) for each.

My data is as below:

| User ID | StartDate | Target Day 0 | Target Day 3 | Target Day 5 | Entry ID | Entry DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID254 | 25/01/2021 16:06 | 25/01/2021 | 28/01/2021 | 30/01/2021 | XYZ060 | 30/01/2021 15:40 |
| ID729 | 14/01/2021 15:03 | 14/01/2021 | 17/01/2021 | 19/01/2021 | XYZ169 | 17/01/2021 12:00 |
| ID729 | 14/01/2021 15:03 | 14/01/2021 | 17/01/2021 | 19/01/2021 | XYZ033 | 28/01/2021 00:00 |
| ID113 | 21/01/2021 18:05 | 21/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | 26/01/2021 | XYZ515 | 23/01/2021 19:15 |
| ID113 | 21/01/2021 18:05 | 21/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | 26/01/2021 | XYZ640 | 25/01/2021 06:20 |
| ID454 | 29/01/2021 13:20 | 29/01/2021 | 01/02/2021 | 03/02/2021 | XYZ433 | 31/01/2021 07:20 |
| ID309 | 26/01/2021 16:42 | 26/01/2021 | 29/01/2021 | 31/01/2021 | XYZ721 | 29/01/2021 10:10 |
| ID062 | 21/01/2021 11:54 | 21/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | 26/01/2021 | XYZ515 | 28/01/2021 17:30 |
| ID062 | 21/01/2021 11:54 | 21/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | 26/01/2021 | XYZ432 | 30/01/2021 23:08 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 12:56 | 19/01/2021 | 22/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | XYZ905 | 23/01/2021 14:35 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 12:56 | 19/01/2021 | 22/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | XYZ950 | 22/01/2021 18:00 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 12:56 | 19/01/2021 | 22/01/2021 | 24/01/2021 | XYZ659 | 25/01/2021 07:28 |

The Entry DateTime should ideally fall on one of the Target Days. But, in reality this rarely happens. So what I'd like to do is allow some flexibility and attribute an Entry DateTime where it has occured on the same day, or up to two days after each Target Day.

**Ideal Output**

| User ID | Target Day 0 | Entry DateTime 0 | Target Day 3 | Entry DateTime 3 | Target Day 5 | Entry DateTime 5 | Entry ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID254 | 25/01/2021 |  | 28/01/2021 |  | 30/01/2021 | 30/01/2021 15:40 | XYZ060 |
| ID729 | 14/01/2021 |  | 17/01/2021 | 17/01/2021 12:00 | 19/01/2021 |  | XYZ169 |
| ID729 | 14/01/2021 |  | 17/01/2021 |  | 19/01/2021 |  | XYZ033 |
| ID113 | 21/01/2021 | 23/01/2021 19:15 | 24/01/2021 |  | 26/01/2021 |  | XYZ515 |
| ID113 | 21/01/2021 |  | 24/01/2021 | 25/01/2021 06:20 | 26/01/2021 |  | XYZ640 |
| ID454 | 29/01/2021 | 31/01/2021 07:20 | 01/02/2021 |  | 03/02/2021 |  | XYZ433 |
| ID309 | 26/01/2021 |  | 29/01/2021 | 29/01/2021 10:10 | 31/01/2021 |  | XYZ721 |
| ID062 | 21/01/2021 |  | 24/01/2021 |  | 26/01/2021 | 28/01/2021 17:30 | XYZ515 |
| ID062 | 21/01/2021 |  | 24/01/2021 |  | 26/01/2021 |  | XYZ432 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 |  | 22/01/2021 | 23/01/2021 14:35 | 24/01/2021 |  | XYZ905 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 |  | 22/01/2021 | 22/01/2021 18:00 | 24/01/2021 |  | XYZ950 |
| ID966 | 19/01/2021 |  | 22/01/2021 |  | 24/01/2021 | 25/01/2021 07:28 | XYZ659 |

**Progress so far**

What I've put together is a CASE statement, as below. But I'd like to know if there's a better way of approaching this.

```
,CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 0 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS 'Target Day 0'
,CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Entry DateTime] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 0 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 2 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) THEN [Entry DateTime] ELSE NULL END AS 'Entry DateTime 0'

,CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 3 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS 'Target Day 3'
,CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Entry DateTime] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 3 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 4 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) THEN [Entry DateTime] ELSE NULL END AS 'Entry DateTime 3'

,CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 5 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS 'Target Day 5'
,CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Entry DateTime] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 5 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST([StartDate] + 7 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) THEN [Entry DateTime] ELSE NULL END AS 'Entry DateTime 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want a `case` expression.  If I understand correctly:

```
select userid, startdate,
       (case when abs(datediff(day, target_date0, entry_date)) <= 2
             then target_date0
        end) as target_date0,
       (case when abs(datediff(day, target_date3, entry_date)) <= 2
             then target_date3
        end) as target_date3,
       (case when abs(datediff(day, target_date5, entry_date)) <= 2
             then target_date5
        end) as target_date5
from t
```